# Error while installing caldecott

Tags: installation, cloud-foundry

I am getting this error while running this command on windows `prompt> gem insatll caldecott`. I have downloaded the development kit but the error is still the same.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

Answer (score 2):

I encounter same error and fix it.

Be sure you carefully follow each step of the [Installation Instructions](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit).
If you test installation successfully on step 5. Just one more thing left to do. To run the devkitvars.bat(lives in ) helper script to update the shell’s %PATH% environment variable. It will add 2 paths.

Here is my PATH variable value after I ran it:
`PATH=c:\Ruby192\DevKit\bin;c:\Ruby192\DevKit\mingw\bin;C:\Ruby192\bin`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the DevKit cannot be found in your path. From the instructions ( https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit ), did you follow step 5 and test the installation?

If that doesn't help, you might try their troubleshooting page: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting